# application/json all requests going to 403

Tags: php, json, ajax, linux, postman

Through postman, I am posting data to specific URL like `site.com/read_request.php`. 
When I am selecting raw data application/xml it gives me output as expected but with application/json it gives me 403

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /tomy/url
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at ......com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I tried with adding

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```

but no luck, from server side can we block only the application/json requests?
If yes how to debug?

Comment: `header("access-control-allow-origin: *");` is a **response** header (not a request header) that only applies when the client is JavaScript running in a web browser. It makes no sense to set it with Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Add a .htaccess file in the folder where you need access on the server.

In that .htaccess file add:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

This makes sure that you can post things to it. **But others can also, so be careful!**